# Allow alpha numeric values instead of isnumeric

Tags: excel, vba, isnumeric

I have the below code for entering a function and copying the orientation and borders of the above line.
But in this it only accept numeric values, how can i modify the code so that i can enter alpa numeric values in that cell.

`Below is the code`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then ' Check if cell contains a numeric value
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Formula = "=IF(B" & Target.Row & "<>"""",ROW()-ROW($A$15)+1,"""")"
            ' Copy border, border color and orientation from row above
            With Range("A" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row)
                .Borders.LineStyle = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.LineStyle
                .Borders.Color = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.Color
                .Orientation = .Offset(-1, 0).Orientation
            End With
        Else
            ' Check if entire row in column B is empty
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row)) = 0 Then
                ' Delete entire row
                Rows(Target.Row).Delete
            Else
                ' Clear contents of column A to H for the row where value was deleted in column B
                Range("A" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small *Function* you could add to your code, to give it `IsAlphaNumeric` functionality.

```
Function IsAlphaNumeric(t) as Boolean
    Dim i as Long
    IsAlphaNumeric = True
    For i = 1 To Len(t)
        If Not (Mid(t, i, 1) Like "[A-z0-9]") Then
            IsAlphaNumeric = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You can use it like this:

```
If IsAlphaNumeric(Target.Value) Then ' Check if cell contains alpha-numeric value
```

Comment: Is this what you were after?